# Font-weight doesn't work when importing from google fonts

Tags: css, sass

Even though the font itself works and I imported the font-weights from google fonts, changing the font-weight value doesn't do anything.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}
```

Also, I checked and I didn't specify the font-weight anywhere else in my file so it shouldn't be a conflict.

EDIT: I didn't know that 400 is default, but also changing it to 500/600 doesn't do anything.

Comment: 400 is being used as the default weight for _all_ text. Change the body to 500 and you will see the difference. https://jsfiddle.net/6Lc7ub4j/

Comment: `400` is default, if you use `500` or `600` you'll see a difference

Comment: What is the problem exactly? you don't see that font-weight rule applied or you don't see the font with weight `400`?

Comment: "but also changing it to 500/600 doesn't do anything" - It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/7083ocbh/ . Do you have the Montserrat font installed on your computer? This may cause problems as your browser will use the installed font rather than the one loaded from Google.

Comment: I didn't know that 400 is the default value, but even if I use 600 it does nothing.

Comment: @Turnip I have 'Montserrat' installed on my computer in all font-weights

Comment: Then try to disable it and test again.